# AspNet.Odata V4 Inject computed getonly properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have an entity Person:

```
public class Person
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Now I build the model

```
public static ODataModelBuilderEx CreatePersonModel(this ODataModelBuilderEx builder)
{
    builder.AddEnum<TypeCode>();
    var persons = builder.EntitySet<Person>("Persons");

    var person = persons.EntityType;
    person.Property(x => x.FirstName);
    person.Property(x => x.LastName);
    return builder;
}
```

Is it possible to expose a computed property 'FullName' without adding this property to the Person class?

Something like this:

```
person
    .Property("FullName", x => x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName)
    .Returns<string>();
```

The returned json should look like this:

```
{
  "FirstName" : "John",
  "LastName" : "Smith",
  "FullName" : "John Smith"
}
```